# Running cucumber without starting starting rails for remote website testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, cucumber, automated-tests

Background: 
I have a rails application with cucumber installed. I would like to use the cucumber tests associated to test the application deployed on a seperate system.

Problem: 
So basically I have the URL for the deployed app and the cucumber tests, so when I start the cucumber with the app link as argument -  **I require cucumber to start the tests without invoking the rails app it is residing with but test the external link.**

Why the need:
Cucumber always try to invoke the postgres database which is causing a problem for me as I am trying to dockerise it and I do not want to include postgres in it(for some reasons that is out of scope here).

So, is it possible to make it happen? (Running cucumber without invoking the other things like the app/call to db)

Answer (score 1):

this can be achieved by defining a rack app that acts as proxy(routing to the endpoint that you want) in your rails app. 
Example:

```
 class TestAppRoutes < Sinatra::Application
    uri = URI.parse("http://10.0.0.0")

    get '/*' do
      request_url = "#{uri}/#{params['splat'][0]}"
      response = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(request_url))

      response
    end

  end
```

And then define a ruby file in the features/support to instantiate the rack app:
if ENV['BASE_URL']
Lookout::Rack::Test.app = APP::TestAppRoutes
end

finally when you are invoking cucumber : do cucumber BASE_URL=http://10.10.10

checkout: https://github.com/lookout/lookout-rack-test